# Twitter tools still showing old username

Tags: wordpress, plugins, twitter

I've recently changed my twitter account and wanted to change the twitter tools plugin for WordPress to DIsplay posts on my WordPress Website

I've changed the Account information to match my new twitter account in the Twitter Tools Options backend and it accepted them and said its connected.

But the Tweets now wont load I just get the message **Loading Tweets**.

When I inspect the page in Console on firebug I see the following error

**"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=oldusername&count=3&callback=json--id number--"**

The username in the Network error and not the new one.

Can Anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Many thanks in advance,

Mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to fix this, someone had declaired the users name in a different file overwriting the username I set in the backend.